# Can I ground a ceiling fan to another electrical ceiling box nearby?

Tags: ceiling-fan, grounding

I want to install a ceiling fan where a ceiling light currently exists in my garage. The box for the current light has only two wires coming in however: a black & a white (no ground - looks like original wiring from 1950's). My question is how can I ground the ceiling fan if I install it in this 2-wire box location? Can I run the ground wire from the ceiling fan to a separate nearby ceiling light box which does have a ground wire coming into it? This nearby ceiling box is on the same circuit (i.e. both the ceiling fan and the nearby electrical box are controlled by the same circuit breaker). I realize I would of course need to first install a ceiling fan rated electrical box to attach the ceiling fan to, but can I ground the ceiling fan to this nearby ceiling light box which is properly grounded back to the circuit breaker panel?

Comment: Is the existing wiring in *metal* conduit with *metal* boxes? If so, that will (typically, not always) function as an effective grounding path.

Comment: What edition of the NEC is your locality on?

Comment: @manassehkatz  Believe it or not, when I removed the light fixture to try and replace it with my ceiling fan, there was NO electrical box at all. The light fixture was screwed into a piece of hard cardboard, and the cardboard was simply resting up on the ceiling drywall. The black & white wires had a cloth type sheathing around them and were connected to the light fixture. So bottom line is I'm installing a new metal ceiling fan rated box. But this box is not grounded.

Comment: @ ThreePhaseEel  I don't know what edition of the NEC, but I'm located in Florida.

Comment: As I understand it (from the pros who have discussed this many times on DIY), retrofit grounds are *now* permitted (that's why the question about NEC edition), so that you can run a separate ground wire to another grounded location, as you described in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to find out which NEC edition governs my locality though. So assuming I can find the NEC edition, then it's just a question of whether this NEC edition for my locale allows a retrofit ground?

Comment: It looks like Florida is on the 2014 NEC. But keep in mind there can be exceptions to various NEC rules in many places - at the state, county or local level.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the NEC edition info for Florida. I will look into any potential exceptions that may apply in my case. I also assume that if a retrofit ground is indeed permitted in my case, I would need to run the separate ground wire to another grounded location that is on the SAME circuit?

Comment: As I understand it, it does NOT need to be the same circuit, but if it is on a different circuit then the ground path has to be big enough the entire distance (e.g., grounding a 20A circuit using the ground path of a 15A circuit would not work unless the 15A ground path (e.g., metal conduit) happened to be adequate for a 20A circuit.

Comment: Thanks again for the info and insights. As it turns out the other grounded location is on the same circuit so I should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes you can

Recent NEC editions allow you to run a retrofit ground wire (equipment grounding conductor) from an ungrounded box/circuit to a grounded branch circuit's ground wire, provided the donor circuit has a large enough ground wire to be a suitable ground for the circuit being retrofitted.  (For instance, if you are grounding a 20A circuit this way, the donor circuit would need to have a 12AWG or larger ground wire.)  The permission for this is given in NEC 250.130(C):

> **(C) Nongrounding Receptacle Replacement or Branch Circuit
>   Extensions.** The equipment grounding conductor of a
>   grounding-type receptacle or a branch-circuit extension shall
>   be permitted to be connected to any of the following:
>
> (1) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode system
>   as described in 250.50
>
> (2) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode conductor
>
> (3) The equipment grounding terminal bar within the enclosure where the branch circuit for the receptacle or
>   branch circuit originates
>
> (4) An equipment grounding conductor that is part of
>   another branch circuit that originates from the enclosure
>   where the branch circuit for the receptacle or branch
>   circuit originates
>
> (5) For grounded systems, the grounded service conductor
>   within the service equipment enclosure
>
> (6) For ungrounded systems, the grounding terminal bar
>   within the service equipment enclosure
>
> Informational Note: See 406.4(D) for the use of a ground-fault
>   circuit-interrupting type of receptacle.

Furthermore, since ground wires do not need to run with the circuit they are grounding as per NEC 300.4(B)(2):

> (2) Grounding and Bonding Conductors. Equipment ground‐
>   ing conductors shall be permitted to be installed outside a race‐
>   way or cable assembly where in accordance with the provisions
>   of 250.130(C) for certain existing installations or in accordance
>   with 250.134(B), Exception No. 2, for dc circuits. Equipment
>   bonding conductors shall be permitted to be installed on the
>   outside of raceways in accordance with 250.102(E).

, you can simply run a bare 14AWG wire from the new ceiling fan box, through the ceiling, to the "donor" box, bring the wire into the box, and connect it to the existing ground wire bundle there.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is exactly what I wanted to do; run a bare ground wire from the new ceiling fan box, through the ceiling, and into the grounded "donor" box. By the way both the new ceiling fan box and the donor box are on the same 15A circuit so this should work nicely with the 14AWG wire I already have.

Comment: Is it OK to use just BARE copper ground wire running through the ceiling to the donor box? As opposed to say running 14-2 Romex, using the ground wire on that to make the grounding connection between the ceiling fan box and the donor box, and capping off the black/white wires in the Romex on both ends. Reason I ask is that at least the ground wire in the Romex is sheathed as opposed to just bare copper wire.

Comment: @Peter -- yes, you can just use a bare copper ground wire running through the ceiling.

Comment: Thank you for the response and all of your insight!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the existing wiring to install a new fixture? This isn't code compliant and it's saving $10 to do it in a manner that's unsafe... Run new wire that's grounded and stop trying to cut corners.

Comment: (a) It may very well be code compliant - there are pros (not me) who will determine that; (b) while in this case it may not be a big deal to run a new cable, there most definitely are times where running a retrofit ground (if permitted) is a **lot** easier than running a new cable.

Comment: If running new wire that's grounded only costs $10 then I completely agree. But my understanding is that running new wiring back to the breaker box is costly.